# Using ipyleaflet in jupyter notebook, map object displays string of text instead of map

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Ipyleaflet map not displaying in Jupyter: I'm trying to display interactive maps using ipyleaflet in a jupyter notebook but am getting a string of "random" text output instead of the map.

I have ipyleaflet v0.10.8 and jupyter notebook v5.7.8. These packages import cleanly. Using Python 2.7.

I have also enabled the ipyleaflet extension through the command line as per the ipyleaflet install documentation even though it wasn't required as I thought this might be the problem:

jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet  # can be skipped for notebook 5.3 and above

I have also tried enabling the following extensions directly in the notebook:

```
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix  
!jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet
```

Jupyter reports that the validation of these two extensions are ok, but I'm still not getting a map to show up, instead the map object is displayed as a line of text. Here's a rundown:

```
#basic map to be displayed in jupyter 
from ipyleaflet import *
import ipyleaflet
print ipyleaflet.__version__
m = Map(zoom=4, basemap=basemaps.Esri.WorldStreetMap)
m
```

This should show a map in the output box, but the output instead is the following line of text:

> TWFwKGJhc2VtYXA9eyd1cmwnOiAnaHR0cDovL3NlcnZlci5hcmNnaXNvbmxpbmUuY29tL0FyY0dJUy9yZXN0L3NlcnZpY2VzL1dvcmxkX1N0cmVldF9NYXAvTWFwU2VydmVyL3RpbGUve3p9L3vigKY=

Any help/suggestions appreciated, I seem to have hit a wall.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure Python 2.7 is supported anymore, is it a strong requirement for you? If not, I suggest updating to Python 3.7. Python 2.7 will not be maintained anymore by the end of the year: https://pythonclock.org/